# Apply CSS to image when browsing directly to it

Tags: css, image

This is probably a stretch, but is it possible to add css to an image in say the URL bar? For example, if I go directly to http://yoursite.com/someimage.png, can I apply css to it without embedding it in a html page?

Comment: what styles do you want to add?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. When the HTTP response returns the binary image data only and not an HTML page there isn't a way for you to control how it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As coreyward has already said, it's not possible to do this with just an image in the browser.

To add something of extra value, what you can do is a bit of url rewrite magic on the server. You can rewrite all requests for images to go to a specific page that handles the request.

In this way you'll be able to do which ever manipulations you'd like too.

Comment: I have the image on a CDN stored in the secure area of the folder which requires a secret key that is hashed in order to access it. I can access the image, however, I need to apply CSS to it because it is displayed in a mobile app in a web view. I suppose I can put the HTML file on the CDN and control access to the HTML file rather than the image itself and pass the image to the HTML page

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work. CSS is used to style the HTML, in case of images the `img`-tag, but not the picture itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a `mod_rewrite` in your `.htaccess` that reroutes direct accesses of the image to a page that just includes the image and styles it. But then you *have* embedded it in a webpage, which isn't what you asked for. Also, you'd have to be careful to ensure that when your site includes the image the rewrite isn't used.

It would go something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?yoursite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*\.png)$ myimagehandler.php?img=$1  [QSA,L]
```

Where `myimagehandler.php` would include the image based on the query string and style it as you like.